# SearchView doesn't work. I don't know if is the database or something else?

Tags: android, database, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I'm working on an app and i have a problem with the searchview, i cannot see results from the database, here's the code

MainActivity.Java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

```
ActionBar actionBar;
Button a;
Button b;
Button c;
Button d;
Button e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Trial");

    initialiseOnClick();
    a.setOnClickListener(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c.setOnClickListener(this);
    d.setOnClickListener(this);
    e.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
     searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
     searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}



private void initialiseOnClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_a);
    b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_b);
    c = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_c);
    d = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_d);
    e = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_e);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button_a:
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EuropeActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    break;

    case R.id.button_b:
        Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AmericasActivity.class);
        startActivity(b);
    break;

    case R.id.button_c:
        Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AsiaActivity.class);
        startActivity(c);
    break;

    case R.id.button_d:
        Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OceaniaActivity.class);
        startActivity(d);
    break;

    case R.id.button_e:
        Intent e = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AfricaActivity.class);
        startActivity(e);
    break;

    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_a"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                    android:text="@string/europe" />


                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_b"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_button"
                    android:text="@string/americas" />


                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_c"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/yellow_button"
                    android:text="@string/asia" />

                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_d"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button"
                    android:text="@string/oceania" />


                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_e"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_button"
                    android:text="@string/africa" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

SearchableActivity.Java

```
    public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
}
DatabaseTable db = new DatabaseTable(this);



private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
        //process Cursor and display results
    }
}
```

}

search.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DatabaseTable.Java

```
    public class DatabaseTable {
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

//The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
public static final String COL_WORD = "WORD";
public static final String COL_DEFINITION = "DEFINITION";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DICTIONARY";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;

public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = COL_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}


private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}



public DatabaseTable(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);

}

private static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                COL_WORD + ", " +
                COL_DEFINITION + ")";

    DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

private void loadWords() throws IOException {
    final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
    InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
            if (strings.length < 2) continue;
            long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
            if (id < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COL_WORD, word);
    initialValues.put(COL_DEFINITION, definition);

    return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


}
```

}

definitions.txt

```
                    abbey - n. a monastery ruled by an abbot
            abide - v. dwell; inhabit or live in
            abound - v. be abundant or plentiful; exist in large quantities
            absence - n. the state of being absent
            absorb - v. assimilate or take in
            abstinence - n. practice of refraining from indulging an appetite especially alcohol
            absurd - j. inconsistent with reason or logic or common sense
            abundant - j. present in great quantity
            abusive - j. characterized by physical or psychological
            academic - j. associated with school or learning
            academy - n. a school for special training
            accept - v. consider or hold as true
            access - v. reach or gain access to
            accessible - j. easily obtained
            acclaim - n. enthusiastic approval
            accommodate - v. provide with something desired or needed
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.trial.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
```

The problem is that i can see the actionbar, i can write in the search dialog, but i can't see results. I know that something is wrong, but i don't know where or what!

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

      @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String key) {
          //After you press Search/Enter control comes here with entered text in "key"
          return true;
        }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String key) {
      //Each time you enter/modify a charcter, control comes here with entered text in "key"
      return true;
      }
});
```